# HTTP API code returns 403 forbidden, however the postman post works - confused

Tags: c#, postman, httpclient

I am trying to integrate the HTTP API from transfernow.net into my windows forms app, but I'm hitting a weird brick wall...

I have tested the API call in postman with my key and it works perfectly, but the below C# is returning a 403 forbidden, can any of you genius coders point out whether I'm got something flawed in my code that would cause this (I have also reached out to Transfernow but expect they will not be responding quickly)

```
static async Task<string> SendPostRequestAsync()
{
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.transfernow.net/v1/transfers"))
                {
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("x-api-key", "xxxxxx"); //removed for security reasons but was the same as used in postman

                    request.Content = new StringContent("{\n        \"langCode\": \"en\",\n        \"toEmails\": [\"my.contact@provider.com\", \"my.other.contact@provider.com\"],\n        \"files\": [{\n          \"name\": \"file1.txt\",\n          \"size\": 14587\n        },{\n          \"name\": \"music.mp3\",\n          \"size\": 5496409\n        }],\n        \"message\": \"A brillant transfer content, thank you\",\n        \"subject\": \"Text and Music\",\n        \"validityStart\": \"2022-10-28T08:52:25.955Z\",\n        \"validityEnd\": \"2022-11-01T08:52:25.955Z\",\n        \"allowPreview\": true,\n        \"maxDownloads\": 7\n      }");
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

                    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // Return the response content as a string
                        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Handle an error response here
                        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + response.StatusCode, "API Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

I've tried converting the curl code from transfernow documentation using https://curl.olsh.me/ and even using postman to generate and neither helped get me passed this issue.

postman generated code as requested :

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api.transfernow.net/v1/transfers");
request.Headers.Add("x-api-key", "xxx");
var content = new StringContent("{\r\n        \"langCode\": \"en\",\r\n        \"toEmails\": [\"ajhbell76@gmail.com\", \"my.other.contact@provider.com\"],\r\n        \"files\": [{\r\n          \"name\": \"P:\\\\events\\\\test\\\\export\\\\DRB_0221woodlands.jpg\",\r\n          \"size\": 2843846 \r\n        },{\r\n          \"name\": \"P:\\\\events\\\\test\\\\export\\\\DRB_0222woodlands.jpg\",\r\n          \"size\": 2843846 \r\n        }],\r\n        \"message\": \"A brillant transfer content, thank you\",\r\n        \"subject\": \"Text and Music\",\r\n        \"allowPreview\": true,\r\n        \"maxDownloads\": 7\r\n      }", null, "application/json");
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

HTTP code generated by postman :

```
POST /v1/transfers HTTP/1.1
Host: api.transfernow.net
Content-Type: application/json
x-api-key: xxxxxx
Content-Length: 517

{
        "langCode": "en",
        "toEmails": ["ajhbell76@gmail.com", "my.other.contact@provider.com"],
        "files": [{
          "name": "P:\\events\\test\\export\\DRB_0221woodlands.jpg",
          "size": 2843846 
        },{
          "name": "P:\\events\\test\\export\\DRB_0222woodlands.jpg",
          "size": 2843846 
        }],
        "message": "A brillant transfer content, thank you",
        "subject": "Text and Music",
        "allowPreview": true,
        "maxDownloads": 7
      }
```

Comment: Yes indeed, that is already in the code : request.Content.Headers.ContentType

Comment: Gabors advice for creating the string content is good but I doubt it is causing the 403. Can you use postman to generate the HTTP code and post it (redacted)?

Comment: I have updated the question with the postman generated code

Comment: I wanted HTTP not c#.

Comment: apologies, added that now

Comment: Does request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation return true?

Comment: yes it returns true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently they also want a `user-agent` header. It would be nice if the documentation mentioned that. I signed up for a trial and only got it to work by setting a user-agent. You probably don't need this exact value, but its what Github CoPilot wrote for me:

`request.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/999.0.9999.999 Safari/537.36");`

I've encountered this before with other APIs. When in doubt, set some kind of user-agent and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `Content-Length` HTTP header is also needed.

```cs
string content = "{\n        \"langCode\": \"en\",\n        \"toEmails\": [\"my.contact@provider.com\", \"my.other.contact@provider.com\"],\n        \"files\": [{\n          \"name\": \"file1.txt\",\n          \"size\": 14587\n        },{\n          \"name\": \"music.mp3\",\n          \"size\": 5496409\n        }],\n        \"message\": \"A brillant transfer content, thank you\",\n        \"subject\": \"Text and Music\",\n        \"validityStart\": \"2022-10-28T08:52:25.955Z\",\n        \"validityEnd\": \"2022-11-01T08:52:25.955Z\",\n        \"allowPreview\": true,\n        \"maxDownloads\": 7\n      }";

HttpContent httpContent =
    new StringContent(
        content,
        Encoding.UTF8,
        // This way you don't need to set Content-Type in a separate statement.
        // Built-in const: "application/json"
        System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Json
    );

// Set the Content-Length header as well.
httpContent.Headers.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content).LongLength;

request.Content = httpContent;
```

Btw. I suggest using `HttpMethod.Post` instead of creating a new instance every time with `new HttpMethod("POST")`.

Comment: [HttpContent.TryComputeLength()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.trycomputelength) -- `403` is not related to the payload, it's related to the account (API key or service availability)